# Create URL using lookup by JNDI with {0} and {1} dynamic values

Tags: java, url, dynamic, jndi

I thoroughly searched for an answer in here but I think my case is pretty isolated.

I'm using IBM Rational® Application Developer 8.5 with WebSphere®. I configured my url from the **Websphere Admin console->Resources->URL->URLs** with these entries:

**name**: Documents_DisplayView

**JNDI name**: url/Documents/DisplayView

**Provider**: Default URL Provider

**Description**: https//Docs.myDomain.ca/velocity/english/secure/DocumentDisplay?DOCUMENT_REFERENCE_NUMBER={0}&DOCUMENT_CONTENT_DATE={1}

To access it from my java class, I created

```
@Resource(lookup = "url/Documents/DisplayView")
private URL docLink;
```

Now I used to hardcode my URLs and just replace the {0} and {1} params with my dynamic values using a text formatter but this time I can't hardcode the " https//Docs.myDomain.ca/..." because it will change depending on the server.

How do I create a URL using JNDI lookup with my formatter java.text.MessageFormat: {0} = value1; {1} = value2?

Thank you.